# Grant all WSO2 users subscriber role by default?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Our organization has set up WSO2 API Manager 2.1, with a secondary user store binding to our organization's LDAP.  We need all users from our organization to have a subscriber role by default.

We would prefer for there to be no need for users to use "Self Sign Up"-- and additionally, "Self Sign Up" appears to create new accounts, however all of our accounts are already in the secondary user store.

How can we configure the system to grant the subscriber role by default?

Comment: I just realized that I can modify the permissions of the 'everyone' role to match 'subscriber' permissions, which should work for us.  I'll leave the question up in case there happens to be a better solution.

Comment: Using the signup functionality, the subscriber role is given to new users (it can be disabled somewhere). if you already have an existing user repository, giving the permissions to the everybody role really seems as the best you could do (imho - good idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any common ldap user group for the users? For example users who need to log in to the store belongs to X group.  If so, you could assign subscriber related permissions for that group from API manager instead of assigning permissions to the 'everyone' role. (If you have configured the groups related ldap queries correctly you should be able to view them in the API manager carbon console. refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Configuring+a+Read-write+LDAP+User+Store)